# How can I Get input value with Prototype?

Tags: prototypejs

I have the following input without any form around it:

```
<input type="text" value="myValue" name="td_website static" class="td_inner_input">
```

How can I get the Input value with prototype? I tried to use `alert($('tb_website static').value);`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
alert($$('[name="td_website static"]')[0].value)
```

Comment: i became an error : `code`alert($('input[name=td_website static]').value); is null `code`

Comment: @code: I have not noticed there is a space in the name (you need to use double quotes to escape names with spaces). Bear in mind that the selector returns an array, not a single element.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the [`$$`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) function which returns an [array](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/). There are a couple of ways to use an [enumerable](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/) result.

If you know there will be only one matching element then use this:

```
$$('[name="tb_website static"]').first().value
```

If there are more than one input (which is valid HTML) then this gets an array of values:

```
$$('[name="tb_website static"]').map(Form.Element.getValue)
```

(By mapping through [`Form.Element.getValue`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/Element/getValue/) - aliased as [`$F`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-F/) - it better handles browser differences and non-`input` elements that don't store their value in a `value` attribute)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that `$('tb_website static')` will be looking for an element with that ID not that NAME.

Have another look at the [PrototypeJS Documentation](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/).

Comment: Thank you! and how to use getbyname here?

Comment: I've no idea if this will work `$$('[name="tb_website static"]')` but that's possibly your best option.

Answer (score 0):

That because `$()` function is an alias for `getElementById()`. Which means you need to give and id in your input :)

```
<input type="text" value="myValue" id="td_website static" name="td_website static" class="td_inner_input">
```

Comment: but now that i use my brin i think there is an other alias, still based on id, but tht returns the value directly, $F() or $A(), but i can't get to find it in google :)

Comment: i cant/shouldnt write an ID into this input!! so i must try it with a getByName!! it's possible??