# How do I take value inside a text field of a html form using prototype.js?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

```
var typeName = Form.getInputs('inputform','text','feature').find(function(text) { return text.checked; }).value;
```

Is this the right way to go about ?

I have applied the same to radio button and it worked .

Comment: If you're trying to get an input's value from it's name rather than ID, consider the suggestions from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5232875/471559

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$F](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-F/) is the shorter way

```
var fooValue = $F('foo')
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean - what other kind of form is there in a html page?

Comment: http://rexchung.com/2007/02/22/getting-radio-buttons-value-with-prototypejs/ . I followed that link .

Comment: Ah, that just describes a workaround because you *can't* use $F for radio buttons.  For every other kind of form input field it's much easier - you can give the field a unique ID and use $F(id)