# Multiples IDs Selection with PrototypeJS

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a prototype question again; look at this HTML :

```
<select id="dropdown_1><option>...</option></select>
...
<select id="dropdown_n"><option>...</option></select>
```

When i just have one `id="dropdown"` and do this :

```
temp_node = $('dropdown').firstDescendant();
default_option = temp_node.innerHTML;
```

It will work!

How can i solve it, in the same way, using many ID looking like mine?

`$$('[id^="dropdown"]').firstDescendant();` doesn't solve my problem either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5232875/471559) you've neglected that [`$$`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) returns an array, not an element.

If you're only interested in getting the option of just one select then you can do it like this:

```
$$('[id^="dropdown"]')[0].firstDescendant();
```

Alternatively, if you want the first option of every matching select do this:

```
var options = $$('select[id^="dropdown"] > option:first-child');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class "dropdown" to each element, and select on that.

BTW your HTML has syntax errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer  maybe it's work!! but in my case i need to call every select individually! the problem is how the select are generated!! i can't change it!! they already come with an id `"dropdown_" + number`;

Comment: @trouble: Change it where you generate them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how many drop downs you have, if so you could do something along the lines of:

```
for(var i=1; i<=MAX_DROPDOWNS; i++) {
    var dropdown = $('dropdown_' + i);
    // Do whatever you need to do with each drop down
}
```

If you don't know how many I think something like this will work:

```
var i=1;
while(var dropdown=$('dropdown_' + i)) {
    // Do whatever you need to do with the drop down.
}
```

Comment: I need to interact indivually with each dropdown! it's within a call function! i need something like this : `$('select[id^="dropdown_"]')` to getting the first child(_option_).